# Super key is not working on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, 23.10

I am unable to perform searches using the super (Windows) key in Ubuntu 23.10. It was functioning correctly, but it suddenly stopped working. Despite attempting various fixes suggested in other questions, none of them resolved the issue.

My keyboard is Logitech k235.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be useful to know what version of Ubuntu you're using. Look at the output of the command `lsb_release -a` and tag your question with 23.10 or 23.04. Are you able to find any error messages anywhere? Can you remember if you changed anything before it stopped working?

Comment: thanks for replying, done in issue description, there is no error messages appears, I remember changing the change language layout shortcut, but I revert it back to the default case.

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 23.10
Release: 23.10
Codename: mantic

Comment: The `Super` key in my instance of 23.10 continues to work perfectly. You need to [edit] your question to include the `Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources` compared to the keyboard you are actually using and `Special Characters Key > Compose Key` settings for completeness and to make your question answerable.

Comment: my keyboard `logitech k235` and i am using Arabic, English input Sourses , special characters are default.